# How do I identify the latest iPad Pro model?

Tags: ipad

How can I tell if an Apple 12.9 inch iPad Pro with Wi-Fi is the latest model? Is the model # enough? Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). 
 What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?  Let's start with that and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has only released one 12.9 inch iPad Pro model so far ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Pro), [EveryMac:iPad Pro 12.9 Wifi](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-pro-1st-gen-wi-fi-only-specs.html), [EveryMac:iPad Pro 12.9 Wifi/Cellular](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-pro-1st-gen-wi-fi-cellular-lte-specs.html)), so the current model in fact is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is the model number you can find it on the back. I made a tool for just this. Checkout [Identify My iPad](https://identifymyipad.com/)